# Count objects created after other object modified date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to count all the posts created after an specific date in a t-SQL query:

```
select a.ParentID as [Post Link]
     , count(DISTINCT a.id) as [Answers after edition]
     , q.LastEditDate as [Last Edition]
     , a.creationdate as [Answered On]
     , DATEDIFF(hour, q.LastEditDate, a.creationdate) as [Hours after edition]
from posts a 
inner join posts q on q.id = a.ParentID
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and a.posttypeid = 2 -- A
and q.LastEditorUserId = ##userid##
and a.creationdate > q.LastEditDate
and q.AnswerCount > 1
group by a.ParentID
```

It results in:

```
Column 'posts.LastEditDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

This query is a modification of this other:

```
select q.id as [Post Link]
     , q.owneruserid as [User Linkl]
     , q.LastEditDate as [Last Edition]
     , a.creationdate as [Answered On]
     , DATEDIFF(hour, q.LastEditDate, a.creationdate) as [Hours after edition]
from posts q 
inner join posts a on a.id = q.AcceptedAnswerId
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and a.posttypeid = 2 -- A
and q.LastEditorUserId = ##userid##
and a.creationdate > q.LastEditDate
order by [Hours after edition]
```

The change consist in that the later only compare post where the AcceptedAnswerId is present. I want to do the same but this time grouping the ones that has the same q.Id.

This is near what I want:

```
select a.id as [Answer Link]
     , q.owneruserid as [User Linkl]
     , q.LastEditDate as [Last Edition]
     , a.creationdate as [Answered On]
     , DATEDIFF(hour, q.LastEditDate, a.creationdate) as [Hours after edition]
from posts a 
inner join posts q on q.id = a.ParentID
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and a.posttypeid = 2 -- A
and q.LastEditorUserId = ##userid##
and a.creationdate > q.LastEditDate
and q.AnswerCount > 1
```

But doesn't group by ParentId.

Rhis is what I expect:

```
Post Link   | Answer Count | Hours after edition
http://link |            3 |                   3
```

I'm not very keen to keeping "Hours after edition" but if it's kept the better.

Comment: Do you have any logic as far as which LastEditDate or creationdate to use if more than one is found for a parent ID? The error it's returning ('posts.LastEditDate' being invalid) is becuase there are no instructions on how to handle multiple values of it. Simple solution for your first query would be to use max(lasteditdate) and min(creationdate).

Comment: WHere is a filter on a column, having is a filter on an aggregate. Under group by parentID put having min(a.creationdate) > max(q.LastEditDate).  (it goes select from where groupby having)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning comments into an answer.  in your first peice of code:

```
 , q.LastEditDate as [Last Edition]
 , a.creationdate as [Answered On]
```

You are getting an error on this because they are not in the group by statement and the script doesn't know what to do with the multiple values.  If you include them in the group by, you may get several rows for each parent ID...I'm thinking you're looking to grab the max date as the last edit and min date as the first creation.

Incidentally...I think you must be on MSSQL here.  If you were in MySQL, it would have executed your query without the group by and just randomly populated those two fields.  ugh Mysql.

Where is a filter on a column, having is a filter on an aggregate.  Since we are moving these to max(date) or min(date), they are becoming aggregates and need to be in the having clause not the where clause.  Select from where group by having is the order you'll need

Final script (provided by Braiam):

```
select a.ParentId as [Post Link]
 , count(DISTINCT a.id) as [Answers after edition]
 --, q.LastEditDate as [Last Edition]
 --, a.creationdate as [Answered On]
 --, DATEDIFF(hour, q.LastEditDate, a.creationdate) as [Hours after edition]
from posts a 
inner join posts q on q.id = a.ParentID
where q.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and a.posttypeid = 2 -- A
and q.LastEditorUserId = ##userid##
and q.AnswerCount > 1
group by a.ParentId
having max(q.LastEditDate) < min(a.creationdate)
```

Comment: "I think you must be on MSSQL here" nope, using the SEDE with T-SQL http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/212873/questions-that-where-answered-after-editing?UserId=169736 and yeah, after reading [this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-147.aspx) it dispelled what the error was.

Comment: AH...was guessing given tsql but not mysql.  We should clean this question...mind if I edit my question to include your final script and we'll leave that as an answer to your question?